# XHTML/CSS editor for Windows with "FTP upload on save" function

Tags: editor

Is there a non-bloated editor with this function?

Answer (score 4):

THe [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor has seamless ftp/sftp editing.

The file is not uploaded on save, but rather the file is loaded directly from the server and *on save* it is written back to the server

Answer (score 2):

Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/download.php) with the [FTP_synchronize](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=189927&package_id=245189) extension. It's small, fast and a pleasure to use. And it's both free and Free.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, WeBuilder has such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

What I use for simple HTML, that has this feature, is [EditPlus3](http://editplus.com/).  Whilst it is shareware, it's an excellent piece of software for hassle-free, non-bloated editing.

Answer (score 0):

PhpED from NuSphere.

Not really an HTML editor. Not really small. But I **really** like it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain.  What I like is to browse a remote FTP tree and edit the files as if they were local.  You press CONTROL-S and it uploads your temp file.  Seems simple, and lots of applications let you keep a list of files open in FTP.

If non-free is ok, Dreamweaver is actually a fantastic tool: just turn all the WYSIWYG stuff off and it's a beautiful and polished editor.

Otherwise, the kinda ageing and free HTML-Kit Build 292 does a pretty serviceable job.
http://www.htmlkit.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

[www.blumentals.net/webuilder/][1]

[1]: http://www.blumentals.net/webuilder/ does exactly this.